# MySQL error: 'invalid use of a group function'

Tags: php, mysql, database, prepared-statement

I have a referral application where an ID can only have 2 direct referrals. I am trying to find IDs which appear less than 2 times in the `ID_REF` field with the code below.

```
$stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT id FROM tb_modules WHERE count(id_ref) < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
                            
$stmt->bind_param("s", $n);
$n = 2;
                            
$stmt->execute();
                            
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
                                                        
$stmt->bind_result($id);
                             
//$stmt->fetch();
                            
$stmt->close();
                            
//echo $id.' '.'oi';
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $id;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @showdev I could not find it yet. May be something wrong with my logic. =/

Comment: Are you using MySQLi? It might be helpful to see if any error messages are generated. See [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: I'd say the $conex handle should be tossed into `var_dump()`. That will tell you what kind of datatype PHP sees it as being.

Comment: conex is ok but the var_dump($stmt) is returning false

Comment: $stmt is returning false because there was an error; your code needs to check for that condition *before* it attempts to call `bind_param`. See my answer for one of the issues with the SQL statement.

Comment: thanks @spencer7593 . It says 'error in prepare invalid use of group function'

Comment: What I am trying to do is to check wich user has't already referred 2 by counting ID_REF

Comment: @showdev I've edited the question to better describe you what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: `WHERE` is applied before the group, so you need to use `GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id_ref) < ?` rather than invoking `WHERE`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it returs '0' when I try SELECT id_ref FROM tb_modules GROUP BY id  HAVING COUNT(id_ref) < ?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking for any errors, that is completely bad development. You should start by ensuring that your `prepare()` is actually preparing the query correctly and not failing...

```
$stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT id FROM tb_modules WHERE count(id_ref) < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
// now check
if(!$stmt) {
    die($conex->error); // or mysqli_error($conex);
} else {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $n);
}
```

Back to other matters. You seem to be trying to compare `count(id_ref)` which would be a number (*`int`*) against `$n` (*which is an `int` too*) but you're trying to pass it as a string.....?

You'll need to change that bind of yours to something like:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $n);
```

Also note, you can't set the `$n` variable after you call it.... that's going to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
var_dump($conex);
$stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT id FROM tb_modules WHERE count(id_ref) < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

var_dump($stmt)
```

This should shed some light on the matter.
I'm betting the `$stmt` variable is bool or null.

Comment: That's obvious. You could've posted that as a comment. You should alternatively edit your answer to attempt to answer the question. I.e. - `if(!$stmt) { echo 'the error...'; } else { bind the query.... }`

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but I think teaching robust coding techniques is beyond the scope. If not, why stop there? Tell him to set the mysqli_options so that only exceptions are thrown? Then it can be done with try\catch\finally.

Comment: Remember, you're here to answer the question, not tell him how to debug it ;-) But i completely understand where you are coming from. If people followed the manual, they'd see how to achieve this properly!

Comment: Thankfully, I don't have to care about opinions of the sheep while answering.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't checking whether `prepare` returned successfully.

If the `prepare` encounters an error, it returns FALSE. instead of a statement object.

And a boolean FALSE value (the return from `prepare`) does not have a method/function `bind_param`.

```
  $stmt = $conex->prepare("...");
  if(!$stmt) {
      echo "error in prepare ". mysqli_error($conex) ;
  } else {
      // prepare returned a statement object so we can do a bind_param
      $stmt->bind_param(...);
```

---

To fix a syntax issue in the SQL statement that's causing an error in prepare, replace they keyword **`WHERE`** with keyword **`HAVING`**.

The predicates (conditions) in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated when rows are accessed. So the result of an aggregate function (e.g. `COUNT()` is not going to be available at the time those conditions in the `WHERE` are check.  There's no way for that condition to be evaluated until *after* the rows are accessed, and the aggregate functions are evaluated. Predicates (conditions) in the `HAVING` clause get evaluated later, so it's valid to reference aggregates in a `HAVING` clause.

Just making that change to the SQL statement isn't likely going to get you the result you are looking for. Without a specification, we're just guessing what you are trying to return.

Comment: Implement using exceptions only. It's more elegant that way. :-)

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: Implement using ORM, Spring framework Java. It's more elegant that way. :-)

Comment: Stay close to true knowledge. Be strong. Resist framework debauchery. ;-)